# Missing boilerplate method implementations with Xcode 4.5

Tags: xcode, xcode4.5

I'm following some xcode lessons that are using xcode 4.2 while I'm using xcode 4.5.2.

In those lessons when a new project is created i can see that there are a lot of built in methods in the ViewController.m like ViewDidAppear etc'. In my ViewController.m there's online - `viewDidLoad and didReceiveMemoryWarning`

Is there a way to get that behavior back or there's something I'm missing in 4.5.2 ?

Comment: I've read this question a couple times and don't understand what you're asking.  Could you restate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't missing anything.

Xcode't templates tend to *evolve* with releases so things come and go. One of those things was all the boilerplate that you used to get with view controllers.

The good news is that you are aware that they are missing so you know which ones to put back if you need to implement them.